# What does "it can refer to people" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> "*I need more people in order to answer the question*" seems to mean that I am going to answer the question. I don't see how ***it can refer to*** people.
> *I need more people to answer the question*." This is ambiguous since it is not clear whether the answer is to be given by *I* or people.”

[Source](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-vs-in-order-to.1598534/)

---

I'd like to know what "***refer to***" means and what "***it***" refers to.

Comment: The source makes the possible intended meanings quite clear. **I need more people to answer the question** (1) - A teacher is asking **more students** to answer his question. (2) - A supervisor of a research project needs more employees so that **they** can answer the question. In principle there's even further ambiguity for sense (2), because it might be "singular they" (so the *supervisor* can answer the question), or "they" might refer to "more employees" doing the answering.

Comment: "it" refers to ***the statement itself***, not "people".

Comment: I modified the title, which was a quotation,  because it seems you were incredulous that "it" was used to refer to people. Feel free to roll back the edit if you prefer the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this is fairly casual writing in a discussion forum.

The word "*It*" here means the whole statement "*I need more people in order to answer the question"*

The sentence "*I don't see how it can refer to people.*" means that the poster (in that other forum) does not understand how the first statement alludes to or involves "people". "The expresion "*refer to*" has its ordinary meaning: A statement  refers to something when it points to or alludes to that thing. This is an intransitive sense of the verb "*refer*". [Merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/refer)n gives for this sense:

> (1b)  to direct attention usually by clear and specific mention; *no one referred to yesterday's quarrel*

Comment: "fairly casual writing" might be relevant if we were examining, say, *I don't see how...* But I don't think using ***it*** to refer to the entirety of a preceding utterance has anything to do with formal / informal writing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers True, such a use of "*it*" can and does occur in every register, from very casual to ultra-formal. My point was only that this example should not be relied on as a source for "correct" usage. Indeed the poster seems to me to be rather confused.

Comment: Well, I suppose there's a line of argument that "formal" writing tends to avoid ambiguity more than "casual" text does. Partly because "casual" very often implies *spoken*, and many potential ambiguities in writing simply vanish when the words are spoken (either because of intonation, or because spoken words almost always occur in a ***full*** context). So perhaps the "supervisor" version of OP's example would be more likely to include disambiguating ***in order to*** in a formal request to his sponsors to ask for more resources! :)